# PHP extract only users from function and insert into db notify table with forech

Tags: php, regex, function, for-loop, foreach

My function extract @users, #hashtags links and emojis from text

```
function convert_text($str) {
            $regex = "/[@#](\w+)/";
        //type and links
            $hrefs = [
                '#' => 'hashtag.php?hashtag',
                '@' => 'user.php?user'
            ];

            $result = preg_replace_callback($regex, function($matches) use ($hrefs) {
                 return sprintf(
                     '<a href="%s=%s">%s</a>',
                     $hrefs[$matches[0][0]],
                     $matches[1], 
                     $matches[0]
                 );
            }, $str);

            //$result = preg_replace("/U\+([A-F0-9]{5})/", '\u{${1}}', $result);
            $result = preg_replace('/U\+([A-F0-9]{5})/', '<span style="font-size:30px;">&#x\\1;</span>', $result);

            return ($result);
        }
```

I would like to create another function to extract **only @users** and 
 insert into `notify` table **foreach @user found on text**
the query is something like :

```
$query = "INSERT INTO notify ('from_user', 'notification') VALUES ('$users_found)
```

maybe

```
foreach($user_found as $user => $u){
    //execute query 
}
```

example: `text here @user1 test @user2`

extract `@user1,  @user2`

and insert on database with `foreach user found`

what is the best way to solve this?

**PDO EXAMPLE**

```
function update_notifications($str) {
    global $conexao_pdo;
    if (preg_match_all("/@(\w+)/", $str, $matches)) {
        $query = "INSERT INTO notification (from_who, type, to_user, time, notification_seen) VALUES (:from_who, :type, :to_user, :time, :notification_seen)";
        $notifications = array();
        foreach ($matches[1] as $user) {
            //$notifications[] = "('$user', '$user found in \'$str\'')";
            $notifications = "('$user')";
        }
        $query .= implode(',', $notifications);
    }
    // execute query
    //echo $query;
    $notification_seen = "no";
    $l = "like";
    $time = date('d-m-Y G:i:s');
$notify = $conexao_pdo->prepare($query);
$notify->bindParam(':from_who', $user_logged);
$notify->bindParam(':type', $l);
$notify->bindParam(':to_user', $notifications);
$notify->bindParam(':time', $time);
$notify->bindParam(':notification_seen', $notification_seen);

$notify->execute();


}

update_notifications('text here @user1 test @otaviobarreto');
```

Comment: Can you show some sample input data and expected output?

Comment: example: `text here @user1 test @user2` extract `@user1,  @user2` and insert on database with `foreach user` found

Comment: @OtávioBarreto Just tried a simple solution to get the result that you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a function like the following to generate and execute a query based on the users found in a given string. It uses [`preg_match_all`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) to find all the users named in a string.

```
function update_notifications($str) {
    if (preg_match_all("/@(\w+)/", $str, $matches)) {
        $query = "INSERT INTO notify (from_user, notification) VALUES ";
        $notifications = array();
        foreach ($matches[1] as $user) {
            $notifications[] = "('$user', '$user found in \'$str\'')";
        }
        $query .= implode(',', $notifications);
    }
    // execute query
    echo $query;
}

update_notifications('text here @user1 test @user2');
```

For the sample string, this will generate the following query:

```
INSERT INTO notify (from_user, notification)
VALUES ('user1', 'user1 found in \'text here @user1 test @user2\''),
       ('user2', 'user2 found in \'text here @user1 test @user2\'')
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/Zpr3Z)

**Update**

Based on the updated code in the question, I think this should work although without access to the database it is not possible for me to test.

```
function update_notifications($str) {
    global $conexao_pdo, $user_logged;
    $query = "INSERT INTO notification (from_who, type, to_user, time, notification_seen) VALUES (:from_who, :type, :to_user, :time, :notification_seen)";
    $notify = $conexao_pdo->prepare($query);
    $notify->bindParam(':from_who', $user_logged);
    $notify->bindParam(':type', $l);
    $notify->bindParam(':to_user', $user);
    $notify->bindParam(':time', $time);
    $notify->bindParam(':notification_seen', $notification_seen);    
    $notification_seen = "no";
    $l = "like";
    $time = date('d-m-Y G:i:s');
    if (preg_match_all("/@(\w+)/", $str, $matches)) {
        foreach ($matches[1] as $user) {
            // execute query
            $notify->execute();
        }
    }
}

update_notifications('text here @user1 test @user2');
```

Comment: I am using PDO, should work also with pdo right? I just need to pass the pdo var into the function.

Comment: @OtávioBarreto yes, just pass the pdo var into the function and then use something like `$result = $pdo->query($query);`

Comment: I updated the question with the PDO bindParam that I need, I am still trying to figure out how to.

Comment: @OtávioBarreto see my edit. I think it should be pretty close to what you need.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the desired result by creating a simple function in php. Also, Here I'm adding an extra space in the string to get the last substring

```
<?php
$string = "text here @user1 test @user2";

$string .= " ";
$result = getStrings($string, '@', ' ');

//print result here
print_r($result);



//pass string, string starting char and end char here
function getStrings($string, $start, $end)
{
    $pattern = sprintf(
        '/%s(.*?)%s/',
        preg_quote($start),
        preg_quote($end)
    );
    preg_match_all($pattern, $string, $matches);

    return $matches[1];
}
?>
```

Output:

> Array (
>       [0] => user1
>       [1] => user2 )